# Meteor NodeJs base64 convert back to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, reactjs, meteor

So in front end I have this piece of code.

```
uploadCallback (file) {
    // TODO: Integrate dropbox with its SDK
    // TODO: Pass the link to the editor
    console.log('file', file)
    this.getBase64(file, this)
  }
  getBase64 (file, self) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log('reader.result', reader.result)
      self.sendFileToServer(reader.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
    }
  }
  sendFileToServer (base64File) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('uploadCallback promise')
        Meteor.call('uploadToDropbox', base64File, function (error, result) {
          console.log('uploadToDropbox callback')
          if (error) {
            console.log('error', error)
          }
          if (result) {
            console.log('result', result)
          }
        })
      }
    )
  }
```

It takes the file object converts to base64 and passes to a called method. And in the server here is my method

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import Dropbox from 'dropbox'
// import atob from 'atob'
import FileAPI from 'file-api'

const { File } = FileAPI

console.log('dropbox settings', Meteor.settings.dropbox)
const dbx = new Dropbox({accessToken: Meteor.settings.dropbox.accessToken})

Meteor.methods({
  'uploadToDropbox': function (base64File) {
    console.log('base64File', base64File.slice(5))
    const b64 = base64File.split(',')
    const name = `${Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5)}.png`
    const file = new File({buffer: new Buffer(b64[1]), name, type: 'image/png'})
    console.log('file', file)
    dbx.filesUpload({path: '/' + file.name, contents: file.buffer})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('dropbox error', error)
      })
    return false
  }
})
```

Here I try to convert the base64File back to file object and upload it to dropbox.
Now here everything seems to be working. The file is being successfully uploaded to the dropbox. However the image itself is empty. And when I download the uploaded image from the dropbox and open it in my computer, the viewer says the file is not a png. So probably my file is not being converted correctly. 
So how can I convert the base64File back to a normal file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
const i = base64File.indexOf('base64,');
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64File.slice(i + 7), 'base64');
const file = new File({buffer: buffer, name, type: 'image/png'});
```